# Unsupervised clustering of strings

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have list of 1000+ keywords that I would like to group together by similarity.

For example:

- "patio furniture"
- "living room furniture"
- "used chairs"
- "new chairs"

I'd like the "furniture" and "chair" terms to cluster together.

I know one way I could do this is to specify some pre-selected "centroid" terms and then compute Levenshtein distances to each and use kmeans to cluster them.

But what I'm interested in finding out is how could I do this without pre-specifying the centroid terms like "chairs" and "furniture".

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `stringdist` package to calculate the distance matrix:

```
str <- c("patio furniture", 
  "living room furniture",
  "used chairs",
  "new chairs")

library(stringdist)
d <- stringdistmatrix(str, str)
```

`stringdist` supports a number of distance functions. The default is the 'restricted Damerau-Levenshtein distance'. You can then use this distance matrix in `hclust` to perform hierarchical clustering:

```
cl <- hclust(as.dist(d))
plot(cl)
```

`hclust` has a number of different methods. See `?hclust`. To create a fixed number of groups (here 2):

```
cutree(cl, 2)
```

But, this is probably one of many possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it could work like this using hierarchical clustering:

```
library(tm)
library(arules) # or other package with (dis)similarity measures... 
docs <- c("patio furniture", "living room furniture", "used chairs", "new chairs")
dtm <- as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(docs))))
# comparse & choose measure, e.g. Jaccard vs Dice Distance
plot(hc <- hclust(dist(dtm, method="binary")), main="Jaccard Dist")
plot(hc <- hclust(dissimilarity(dtm, method="Dice")), main="Dice Dist")
# determine cutting distance (e.g. 0.6)_
clusters <- cutree(hc, h=.6)
# result
cbind.data.frame(docs, clusters)
#                    docs clusters
# 1       patio furniture        1
# 2 living room furniture        1
# 3           used chairs        2
# 4            new chairs        2
```